# Following the definiton of projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-space, projection-matrices

We know a square matrix $A$ that gives vector space projection  from $R^n$ to its subspace, say, $V$ is indeed a projection matrix if $A^2 = A$.

If I had, for example, a square matrix $B$ which satisfies $B^3 = B$:

- Would $B$ be still considered a valid projection from $R^n$ to a subspace, say, $W$?
- If not, would $B^2$ be a projection from $R^n$ to its own corresponding subspace?

Thank you in advance for any commentary.

Comment: (1) No, not really (consider the negative identity matrix).
(2) Yes, because $(B^2)^2 = B^4 = B^3B = BB = B^2$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the transition $B^3B = BB$, please? You may post it as an answer, so I can upvote it.

Comment: $B^3B = BB$ because you *assume* that $B^3=B$.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thank you. Still may post an answer if you feel like so.